# Automatic Concatenated value

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, bigdata, auto-increment

I want to generate automatic concatenated value in a database table, I need a value like this:

```
1000/03-24-2019/11:51
```

in SQL Server.

For example:

```
CREATE TABLE tickets 
(
     tiknum VARCHAR(50) IDENTITY(1000, 1) + / + SYSTEMDATETIME PRIMARY KEY,
     salecode INT
)
```

Can something like this be achieved without having to do it in the backend of my app? That the DB generates it automatically?

Answer (score 1):

The identify is sufficient as a primary key.  There is no reason to append anything else to it.  So, I would suggest:

```
CREATE TABLE tickets (
    tiknum int identity(1000, 1) primary key,
    createdat datetime default getdate(),
    salecode int
);
```

If you want a column with the values concatenated together, you can use a generated column:

```
CREATE TABLE tickets (
    tiknum int identity(1000, 1) primary key,
    createdat datetime default getdate(),
    salecode int,
    full_tiknum as (convert(varchar(255), tiknum) + '/' + createdat)
);
```

Comment: thank you very much this is what I needed, I did not know how to do it.

Comment: CREATE TABLE tickets (
    tiknum int identity(1000, 1) primary key,
    createdat datetime default getdate(),
    salecode int,
    full_tiknum as (convert(varchar(255), tiknum) + '/' + createdat)
);